# Save the wysiwyg Custom Tinymce Button last Input on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wysiwyg

I've created a light/Dark mode switch button in wordpress which change the background color of the editor with inline css to the body throught the tinymce pluginmanager

The problem is that everytime the page loads, the last input (the last light/dark mode) it's not saved by the editor because I presume that the wysiwyg doesn't have that functionality to begin with as it's actually saved every styling and text into the database.

Is there any way to save the last input of the custom button by somehow putting it into my own database?

Thank you